# awk calculation fails in cases where zero is used

Tags: awk

I am using `awk` to calculate `%` of each `id` using the below, which runs and is very close except when the `#` being used in the calculation is zero.  I am not sure how to code this condition into the `awk` as it happens frequently.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
ABCA2 9 232
ABHD12 211 648
ABL2 83 0
```

**file2**

```
CC2D2A 442
(CCDC114) 0
```

**awk with error**

```
awk 'function ceil(v) {return int(v)==v?v:int(v+1)}
>         NR==FNR{f1[$1]=$2; next} 
>        $1 in f1{print $1, ceil(10000*(1-f1[$1]/$3))/100 "%"}' all_sorted_genes_base_counts.bed all_sorted_total_base_counts.bed > total_panel_coverage.txt
awk: cmd. line:3: (FILENAME=file1 FNR=3) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: What result should you get when `$3` is zero? `N/A`?

Comment: I apologize for not posting both inputs files and will edit my post.... sorry was running into a meeting.  Thank you :).

Comment: "N/A" would be perfect... Thank you :).

Comment: Since `awk` does not have manageable exceptions for divide by zero, just add the appropriate logic detect it before you divide by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a script that fails when parsing 2 input files, I can't imagine why you'd only show 1 sample input file and no expected output thereby ensuring

1. we can't test our potential solutions against a sample you think is relevant and
2. we have no way of knowing if our script is doing what you want or not,

but in general to guard against a zero denominator you'd use code like:

```
awk '{print ($2 == 0 ? "NaN" : $1 / $2)}'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo '6 2' | awk '{print ($2 == 0 ? "NaN" : $1 / $2)}'
3

$ echo '6 0' | awk '{print ($2 == 0 ? "NaN" : $1 / $2)}'
NaN
```